# How to literally translate this: 会因为费用增加而让投资人不高兴?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

大导演非常着急，一来，耽误了时间，日程就得重新安排；二来，会因为费用增加而让投资人不高兴，至于这部影片的投资人，...

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 26.

How to literally translate this: 会因为费用增加而让投资人不高兴?

I have reached to the following point: 会因为(?)费用(costs)增加(increase)而(?)让(make)投资人(investors)不高兴(unhappy)

I know that 会 as hui4 means union or to know and 因为 as yin1 wei4 means because, since or as, but what exactly is the meaning of 会因为 here? 而 as er2 means and or then, but what about here?

Answer (score 1):

> 会因为费用增加而让投资人不高兴。

This sentence has an implicit subject, roughly "this situation" (这样, 这种情况). Let's first delete the 因为 part:

> 这样会让投资人不高兴。

会 can be used as a auxiliary verb (助动词) to express future possibility. See 现代汉语描写语法 p.878, 现代汉语八百词增订本 p.278. Examples are:

> 看样子明天会下雨。 (It looks like it's going to rain tomorrow.)
>
> 他一定会成功的。 (He will succeed.)

Occasionally 会 is also used for unexpected possibilities of current and past events.

> 他怎么会知道的？ (How did he know it? I did not expect the possibility that he would know it.)

Hence 这样会让投资人不高兴 = This will make the investors unhappy.

因为 inserts a clause that explains the reason. The purpose of 而 is to mark the end of that clause. 因为费用增加 = due to the rise of costs. For other conjunction uses of 而, see 现代汉语描写语法 p. 209, 现代汉语八百词增订本 p. 192-194.

Answer (score 1):

> (那)会因为费用增加而让投资人不高兴

Because of differences in grammar, word choice, and arrangement, I think the translation should be:

- (It/That) will[会] then[因而] make[让/造成] the investors unhappy[投资人不高兴] because of[因为] cost escalation[费用增加].
- It/That will then make the investors unhappy because of cost escalation.

Answer (score 1):

会因为费用增加而让投资人不高兴
(the delay), because the costs will increase, will make the investors unhappy

大导演非常着急，
The great director is very worried,
一来，
first,
耽误了时间，
(if) the (release) time is delayed,
日程就得重新安排；
the (screening) schedule will have to be rearranged;
二来，
secondly,
会因为费用增加而让投资人不高兴，
because of the increase in costs the investors will be unhappy,
至于这部影片的投资人，
(and) as for the investors in this film ...